# Jaws is reading input field of above fieldgroup

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

```html
<div class="ms-Panel-content content-410">
  <div class="panelSubheadingStyle-396">
    We recommend you keep only one phone number and one address in your profile
    for easy communication.
  </div>
  <fieldset class="groupedElements-421">
    <legend class="legendStyle-422">
      <label class="ms-Label titleLabelStyle-423">Phone number</label>
    </legend>
    <div class="ms-TextField root-425">
      <div class="ms-TextField-wrapper">
        <div class="ms-TextField-fieldGroup fieldGroup-426">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="TextField134"
            maxlength="15"
            class="ms-TextField-field field-427"
            aria-label="add phone number"
            aria-invalid="false"
            value="545465464"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <h3 class="panelSubheadTitleStyle-397">Address</h3>
  <fieldset class="groupedElements-436">
    <legend class="legendStyle-422">
      <label class="ms-Label titleLabelStyle-423"
        >Street address<span class="requiredLabelStyle-419"
          >&nbsp;(required)</span
        ></label
      >
    </legend>
    <div class="ms-TextField root-425">
      <div class="ms-TextField-wrapper">
        <div class="ms-TextField-fieldGroup fieldGroup-426">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="TextField139"
            aria-required="true"
            maxlength="100"
            class="ms-TextField-field field-427"
            aria-label="add street address"
            aria-invalid="false"
            value="asd"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="groupedElements-436">
    <legend class="legendStyle-422">
      <label class="ms-Label titleLabelStyle-423"
        >City<span class="requiredLabelStyle-419">&nbsp;(required)</span></label
      >
    </legend>
    <div class="ms-TextField root-425">
      <div class="ms-TextField-wrapper">
        <div class="ms-TextField-fieldGroup fieldGroup-426">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="TextField144"
            aria-required="true"
            maxlength="100"
            class="ms-TextField-field field-427"
            aria-label="add city"
            aria-invalid="false"
            value="city input"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="groupedElements-436">
    <legend class="legendStyle-422">
      <label class="ms-Label titleLabelStyle-423"
        >Country/region of residence<span class="requiredLabelStyle-419"
          >&nbsp;(required)</span
        ></label
      >
    </legend>
    <div class="ms-ComboBox-container dropdownStyle-394">
      <div
        data-ktp-target="true"
        id="ComboBox149wrapper"
        class="ms-ComboBox css-437"
      >
        <input
          autocapitalize="off"
          autocomplete="off"
          aria-autocomplete="inline"
          data-ktp-execute-target="true"
          data-is-interactable="true"
          id="ComboBox149-input"
          class="ms-ComboBox-Input css-438"
          type="text"
          aria-expanded="false"
          role="combobox"
          aria-label="select your country or region"
          aria-describedby="ComboBox149-error"
          spellcheck="false"
          placeholder="Select a country/region"
          data-lpignore="true"
          value="Venezuela"
          style="font-family: inherit"
        /><button
          type="button"
          class="ms-Button ms-Button--icon ms-ComboBox-CaretDown-button root-446"
          role="presentation"
          data-is-focusable="false"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <span
            class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-67"
            data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"
            ><i
              data-icon-name="ChevronDown"
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="ms-Icon root-32 css-321 ms-Button-icon icon-447"
              style="font-family: FabricMDL2Icons"
              ></i
            ></span
          >
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="groupedElements-436">
    <legend class="legendStyle-422">
      <label class="ms-Label titleLabelStyle-423"
        >State/province<span class="requiredLabelStyle-419"
          >&nbsp;(required)</span
        ></label
      >
    </legend>
    <div class="ms-ComboBox-container dropdownStyle-394">
      <div
        data-ktp-target="true"
        id="ComboBox153wrapper"
        class="ms-ComboBox css-437"
      >
        <input
          autocapitalize="off"
          autocomplete="off"
          aria-autocomplete="both"
          data-ktp-execute-target="true"
          data-is-interactable="true"
          id="ComboBox153-input"
          class="ms-ComboBox-Input css-438"
          type="text"
          aria-expanded="false"
          role="combobox"
          aria-label="select your state or province"
          aria-describedby="ComboBox153-error"
          aria-disabled="false"
          spellcheck="false"
          placeholder="Select a state/province"
          data-lpignore="true"
          value=""
          style="font-family: inherit"
        /><button
          type="button"
          class="ms-Button ms-Button--icon ms-ComboBox-CaretDown-button root-446"
          role="presentation"
          data-is-focusable="false"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <span
            class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-67"
            data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"
            ><i
              data-icon-name="ChevronDown"
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="ms-Icon root-32 css-321 ms-Button-icon icon-447"
              style="font-family: FabricMDL2Icons"
              ></i
            ></span
          >
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

JAWS is not announcing text field information properly when focusing on 'city' text fields, as Jaws is reading previous field content information (street text box value). JAWS is reading the previous field value. When moved by the down arrow key to the city or street address field. It should only announce the input field value of the field which is focussed and not the field above it.

Comment: I’m not sure if it might be related, by the `<label>` element is misused here. It needs to be related to a field. At the same time, `<fieldset>`s are used to wrap single inputs, which is also a misuse. It’s intended to group _several_ fields. I recommend using the `<label>` is intended by wrapping it around the `<input>`, or adding a `for` attribute, and discarding the fieldsets. That might solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `<legend>` here. **Don't use legend to label the controls inside a fieldset!**

Don't put `<label>` in `<legend>`. The legend is already a kind of label.

A `<fieldset>` is primarily a **semantic grouping** mechanism, labelled by (i.e. "accessibly named by") the (optional) `<legend>`. The legend labels **the entire group**, rather than any of its individual "children".

Yes, it is valid to have a fieldset containing only one control (or none at all), but ... why would you want to do this? That just adds complexity, unwelcome chatter (and extra keypresses) to the assistive tech experience of your content. As you have discovered, it also confuses the JAWS screen reader.

Don't be seduced by the default visual appearance of a fieldset. It is **not** purely presentational - it actually means something, so it will be included in the accessibility tree and will be announced by screen readers - as a **group**, not as a control.

If you would like to have a presentational box around each control, add some CSS borders to the wrapper divs you have used already.

It might make sense for all these controls to be inside a single fieldset with legend "Contact Info" or something like that.

Then, use `<label>` elements with `for` attributes pointing at the id of the relevant control. Typically, the label will appear just before or after the control (or its wrapper div) in the DOM.

The `for` attribute is how the screen reader knows which label is associated with which control. With the `for` attribute in place, you can (and should) **remove** the `aria-label` attributes entirely. It's always better to use the onscreen label as the accessible name, if possible.

BTW why are your buttons marked as presentational? Why not use semantic HTML instead of ARIA? You've used `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`, why not `<select>`?